# Do single page applications cause indexing problems for site search solutions?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, search, single-page-application

While I've seen a lot of discussion on how Single Page Applications can present challenges for Search Engine Optimization due to indexing issues, I can't find any information about whether using site search solutions (such as Swiftype, Algolia, etc.) presents similar challenges. If it doesn't, what is the relevant difference between how a search engine sees a site and how a site search solution sees a site?

Comment: If you want to have deep links into your content from search engines or site search you shouldn't be implementing your site as a single page application.  SPAs are great for tools but are awful at presenting multiple pages of content that can be deep linked.

Comment: Some SPA frameworks use pushState to create "pages" that aren't powered by new page views.  That can work OK for search engines when you use regular links to those pages.  However Googlebot can't crawl most sites built on Angular at all.  We get tons of frustrated question about that here.

Comment: I've use site search that works two ways:  1.  Something crawls your site and indexes your content.   2.  You provide words and URLs from your database.   Site search based on a crawler is going to be problematic because crawlers that execute JavaScript are very hard to build. Even ones like Googlebot that do so are far from perfect.   If you provide the content from your DB and you allow deep links via pushState, you could be OK.   I'm not familiar with either of the two you mention in your question specifically, so I don't know which type they are.